# RXJS observables cancel mouseover stream after mouseout event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Trying to implement an rxjs observable pipeline in React.

Codesandbox example -> https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-fog-xtdi4

Creating a html element (div) in React, and binding mouseover and mouseout events.

React Code to initialize this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const elMouseOut$ = fromEvent(elRef.current, "mouseout").subscribe(() =>
      setState({ hover: "mouseout", eventType: "mouseout" })
    );

    const elMouseOver$ = fromEvent(elRef.current, "mouseover")
      .pipe(debounceTime(2000))
      .subscribe(() =>
        setState({ hover: "mouseover", eventType: "mouseover" })
      );

    return () => {
      elMouseOver$.unsubscribe();
      elMouseOut$.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Acceptance criteria Steps.

1. When I mouse over, after a delay of 2 seconds i need to make a state update.
2. If I mouse out at any time BEFORE the 2 second delay I need to cancel the mouseover stream, and set some state. (**THIS STEP IS BROKEN**)
3. If I mouse out any time AFTER the 2 second delay, I need to set some state.
4. This should be repeatable, in the sense that if i mouse over, mouse out and mouse over again we start from Step 1.

I have tried several different combinations of operators, but cannot get things working as expected.

Note: If the mouse over debounce time is met, an ajax request is made.

Any help/advice would be appreciated, i simply do not have the rxjs chops to sort this one out.

Answer (score 1):

[CodeSandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bhabha-oujhr?file=/src/Element.js:1162-1637).

---

I think this could be a way to solve it:

```js
const sub = merge(
  elMouseOver$.pipe(
    // Step 4)
    // Repeating the steps with the help of `switchMap`
    switchMap(() =>
      timer(2000).pipe(
        // Step 2).
        // Cancelling the stream and setting some state(have a look at '3)', below).
        takeUntil(elMouseOut$),

        // Step 1).
        // This will be invoked if 2 seconds have passed after the mouseover event without
        // the mouseout event taking place.
        tap(() => setState({ hover: "mouseover", eventType: "mouseover" })),
      )
    )
  ),
  // Step 3).
  // Setting the state.
  elMouseOut$.pipe(
    tap(() => setState({ hover: "mouseout", eventType: "mouseout" }))
  )
).subscribe();
```

Also, because we're subscribing to `elMouseOut$` multiple times, you might want to use the `share()` operator so that only one event listener will be added:

```js
const elMouseOut$ = fromEvent(elRef.current, "mouseout").pipe(
  share(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const elMouseOver$ = fromEvent(elRef.current, "mouseover");
    const elMouseOut$  = fromEvent(elRef.current, "mouseout");

    const mouseoutSub = elMouseOver$.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        tap(() => setState({ hover: 'mouseover', eventType: 'mouseover' })),
        switchMap(() => elMouseOut$),
        tap(() => setState({ hover: 'mouseout', eventType: 'mouseout' })),
        takeUntil(scheduled(elMouseOut$, asyncScheduler)),
        repeat()
    );

    return () => mouseoutSub.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Flow:

- [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) - after mouseover, wait 2 seconds
- [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) - set `mouseover` state
- [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) - listen for `elMouseOut$`
- [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) - set `mouseout` state
- [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) - end stream when mouseout occurs
- [`repeat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/repeat)

Since `switchMap` and `takeUntil` are using the same source, I used [`scheduled`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/scheduled) inside the `takeUntil` so that the `switchMap` would have a chance to emit before the observable was completed.

---

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68716982?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=60) that demonstrates this behavior.